# Using multiple Storyboards in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created 5 extra Storyboards and I have deleted the main storyboard.  This is because I would like to have 5 separate storyboards for the iPhone and iPad to match 5 different screen sizes.  So far I have one for the iPhone 3.5 inch, one for the iPhone 4 inch, one for the iPhone 4.7 inch, one for the iPhone 5.5 inch and one for the iPad. I have put the code bellow in to link it all up and make it work. However, it doesn't work when you try and build the project.  There is no errors but lets say I go into the iPhone 3.5 inch storyboard and I add a UIViewController and a Button or label, then when you build the project it goes to your launch screen and then it doesn't do anything from there.  I have put the starting arrow in at the UIViewController but I cannot get anything to come up apart from the launch screen.  I have tried this on all the storyboards and their simulators.  I am wondering if I have missed something out in the code but I am not sure.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPad" bundle:nil];//iPad
} else {
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (screenSize.height == 480){
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone4S" bundle:nil];//iPhone 3.5inch
    } else
        if (screenSize.height == 568){
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone5/5C/5S" bundle:nil];//iPhone 4inch
        }
        else
        { if (screenSize.height == 667){
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone6" bundle:nil];//iPhone 4.7inch
            } else
                if (screenSize.height == 736){
                    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone6Plus" bundle:nil];//iPhone 5.5inch
                } else
                    //default storyboard
                storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.Storyboard" bundle:nil];
            }
}
    self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find your info.plist file in your project and remove the line called "Main storyboard file base name". [image]

Also, you forgot to create the window (credits to [rdelmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285133/rdelmar)).

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

I strongly advise you to look into [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html). Using these two, you can support all screen sizes within one single Storyboard. It's a bit hard to get in the beginning, but it'll definitely be worth it in the long run.

There's a video about this from the most recent WWDC called [Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?include=216#216).

Comment: Thanks for that.  But now it just goes to a black screen instead of my UIViewController that has a label saying Hello.  Same thing happens on the other sizes too.

Comment: You can also do this by clicking on the project and going to the General pane. There, just delete where it says "Main" in the Main Interface field.

Comment: @BenjaminMcIntyre, you need to create the window also. self.window is going to be nil in your code.

Comment: @rdelmar, How do you create a window?  Sorry I am fairly new to this.

Comment: @BenjaminMcIntyre, self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; You also need to make it visible before returning YES at the end, [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: Sorry,  Where do I put this.

Comment: @BenjaminMcIntyre, you create the window as the first line in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and add the makeKeyAndVisible as the last line before return YES.

Comment: @rdelmar, Thank you so much.  This has fixed the problem.

Comment: @benjaminMclntyre, This does not work for me, it only works for my iPhone 5 running iOS 7. Did you use this on an iOS 8 device or iOS 7

Comment: @msweet168 It really shouldn't be different depending on if it's iOS 7 or iOS 8. Is the device running iOS 8 your simulator? Have you tried cleaning your project's derived data?

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is my app was a landscape app so you have to change the word height to width. Also for the iPhone 6 and 6 plus you need to have a launch image or its not going to work.