# Xcode choose storyboards at launch (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I had an app with two storyboards, one for the 4inch screen and one for the 3.5 inch screen. I had the following code in my "didfinishlaunchingwithoptions" to load the right storyboard at launch...

```
 if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

    if(result.height == 960){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"3inchstoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    }
}
```

With the release of Xcode 6 and iOS 8, this no longer works how it should, it just loads up the storyboard for the 4inch every time no matter what device, do you know how I can get this to work on iOS 8 in Xcode 6?

Comment: Maybe you can find your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086305/using-multiple-storyboards-in-xcode (note the plist thing)

Comment: A better question would probably be "how I can make the same storyboard work on 3.5 and 4 inch screens", since you now also have the iPhone 6 and 6 plus to worry about, your solution is fast becoming unsustainable.

Comment: This works fine on the 6 and 6 plus just not the 4, and the link that @yaser gave me is good but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can have these conditions, one for iPhone 4,4s (960) and the other for 5,5s,6,6plus (1136) the last for ipads

```
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

        if(result.height == 960){ //storyboard for 4,4s
            storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard4" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
            [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
        }
        if(result.height == 1136){ //storyboard for 5,5s,6,6plus
            storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard5" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
            [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
        }
    }else { //storyboard for ipads
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboardipad" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    }
```